# Python: Simplify variable declaration (with a for loop ?)

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, declaration

I'm new to python and I have declared some variables in my code but they are almost similar, I would like to know if it is possible to simplify this with a `for` loop or the like so as not to have 10 lines of declaration?

```
Left_10 = PhotoImage(file = 'image_10.jpg')
Left_9 = PhotoImage(file = 'image_9.jpg')
Left_8 = PhotoImage(file = 'image_8.jpg')
Left_7 = PhotoImage(file = 'image_7.jpg')
Left_6 = PhotoImage(file = 'image_6.jpg')
Left_5 = PhotoImage(file = 'image_5.jpg')
Left_4 = PhotoImage(file = 'image_4.jpg')
Left_3 = PhotoImage(file = 'image_3.jpg')
Left_2 = PhotoImage(file = 'image_2.jpg')
Left_1 = PhotoImage(file = 'image_1.jpg')
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: don't do that. use proper data structure. Check http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dict:

```
Left = {i: PhotoImage(file = 'image_'+str(i)+'.jpg') for i in range(1,11)}
```

and access with `Left[7]`

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a copy of what @Julien said, but as a `list` instead of a `dict`:

```py
Left = [PhotoImage(file=f"image_{i}.jpg") for i in range(1, 11)]
```

And you can access them by index and sort them (unlike the `dict`):
`Left[0]  # PhotoImage with file=image_1.jpg`...